# linux mysql_secure_installation access denied error

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

I'm trying to install mysql on my fedora 33 system, but when I run the command `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and enter the temporal password (I copy and paste it from the result of the command `sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log` I get the following error: "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". I also executed the command `sudo mysql -u root -p`and with it I get the exact same problem. Is there a way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: clean data directory and run `mysql_secure_installation` then use password which you'll get in log file.

Comment: I tryed deleting the mysql files and reinstalling from the main fedora repos but when I run mysql_secure__installation i get the same error, idk if i'm supposed to use the password that I get from the output of the command 'sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log', because when I use it I still get that error

Comment: hope you followed all steps as mentioned in this link: https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-fedora/

Comment: that file could have more password can you check with command `grep 'A temporary password is generated' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -1`

Comment: I used the method described in the official oracle page and the docs.fedora page (both with the oracle repos and the main ones) and still get the same error. When using the password that the output of `grep 'A temporary password is generated' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -1` gives me I still get  the same error, so i still don't know how to make this work.